# Removing constraints that were added programatically

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

I read many topics about how to remove constraints that were added through the storyboard, drag outlet and then remove etc. but how I can remove constraints that were added programmatically? For example

```
firstView.topAnchor.constraints(equalTo: secondView.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
```

how can I deactivate it and then enable it again if needed. Maybe it should be something like?

```
firstView.removeConstraint(firstView.topAnchor.constraints(equalTo: secondView.bottomAnchor))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should assign your constraint to a property in your `ViewController`. And then set `.isActive` to `false` instead of true.

Your code should look like this:

```
let myConstraint = firstView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondView.bottomAnchor, constant: 15)
```

Now, to activate it:

```
myConstraint.isActive = true
```

And to disable it:

```
myConstraint.isActive = false
```

Comment: @Sargot You are welcome! If you have questions about this approach, make sure to ask.

Comment: Is the only way to change the height or width to keep a reference to the previous height or width and remove that constraint before adding new one?

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep a reference to your constraint.

```
let constraintName: NSLayoutConstraint = firstView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondView.bottomAnchor, constant: 15)
constraintName.isActive = true
```

Disable it when you don't need it.

```
constraintName.isActive = false
```

Enable it when you want it back.

```
constraintName.isActive = true
```

Comment: `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor` has no member `constraints`

Comment: It should be `topAnchor.constraint()`, not `topAnchor.constraints()`. Also the explicit type annotation `:NSLayoutConstraint` is not needed

Comment: My bad, I just copied his line. Didn't put it through the compiler. It is fixed now.

Comment: does that mean if we want to change the button size arbitrarily over the course of the program it will accumulate a ridiculous number of constraints? Is there no other way?

Answer (score -3):

Remove constraints will be deprecated in future.

Here is the alternate way to do the same.

Enable/Disable constraints do with below methods

**Objective-C**

```
viewHeightConstraint.active = YES;      // Enable
viewHeightConstraint.active = NO;       // Disable
```

**Swift**

```
viewHeightConstraint.isActive = true   // Enable
viewHeightConstraint.isActive = false  // Disable
```

Comment: what is viewHeight? is this is the view that you are going to activate/diactivate? I thought it's working only for constraints. Sorry, I do not understand your answer at all

Comment: `YES` and `TRUE` are booleans in Objective-C

Comment: only for programmatically  constraint code enable and disable